# AWS S3 Ruby using aws-sdk gem version 2 creating folders programatically and write image url's into them which are strings in my database

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I am using aws-sdk gem version 2 and I am trying to create folders/files on my bucket. Each folder should be populated with image urls from my database (they are not real files on my system). I need to put these 'images' on this bucket folders on aws s3. Bucket folders must have the same name as id of the 'image' in my DB (this id is of the form '84675683' for example). So I have something like this:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'region', access_key_id: ENV['ACCESS_KEY'], secret_access_key: ENV['SECRET_KEY'])
s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']).object('special id which is in my db related to every image').put(body: 'image url which is string')
```

This is not creating folders but some kind of files on which I can't click (they don't behave like folders on which I can click to open contents) and which are not populated with anything. Please help, I am out of ideas.